# How to change margin of non-existing element

Tags: javascript, image, margin, event-propagation

After i get data from the api, I want to change it's margin. But it's not originally in the html, I'm thinking about event propagation but I couldn't do even if i research.

It's how i get the data

```javascript
const getImages = async function () {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
  const data = await res.json();
  data.map((img) => {
    const markup = `
        <img
          src="${img.url}"
          alt="Image"
          title="${img.title}"
          width="100%"
        />
    `;
    imgContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
  });
};
```

I tried event propagation but i couldn't think a proper event for this

```javascript
const propagation = function () {
  imgContainer.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you just inline the style in the markup var? Or add a class attribute with the margin you want set?

Comment: @Shaun Actually yes, adding class makes sense

Comment: Great, thanks. I've made my comment an answer. If you can upvote and give it a tick please :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just inline the style in the markup var? Or add a class attribute with the margin you want set?